# How to copy ownership and permissions using rsync but not the files?

Tags: linux, permissions, deployment

I am using AWS CodeDeploy to copy files from git to the server. It can't overwrite the files, so I have to move the files to another temp location and then it moves the files from the repo to the original server `/var/www`.

I'd like to keep the permissions for the directories and files the same as before and so can I use `rsync` to sync only permissions and ownership using the older files in the temp folder to this new folder, but not the files themselves?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK there are no rsync flags to only sync ownership and permissions but both the `chmod` and `chown` commands support a `--reference` flag.

You can point to an existing file and `chmod` will use the permissions of that file instead of you needing to supply MODE values when changing the file mode.
Similarly `chown` will use the owner and group of that reference file/directory rather than specifying OWNER:GROUP values.

You can then do something along the lines of:

```
cd /template/
find . -exec chmod -v --reference='{}' /path/to/target/'{}' \;
find . -exec chown -v --reference='{}' /path/to/target/'{}' \;
```

Comment: For the `chown` command I get a `cannot access` error when it tries to match with files in target subdirectories, even though the reference and target folders have the same exact trees.